# Changed font of feature and got "Assertion failed: Expected feature to be removed from index"

Tags: openlayers-3

I've got a roundtrip drawn with openlayers.
The different points have a style like that :

```
new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 2,

            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(1,0,0,0)'
            })
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: 'normal 600 12px Calibri, sans-serif',
            text: feature.get('TEXT'),
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: +12,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(1,0,0,0)'
            })
        })
    })
```

I want to modify the font for a specific event (export png), so for each feature I'm changing the font

```
for (var i = 0; i < vector_service_port.getSource().getFeatures().length; i++) {
  vector_service_port.getSource().getFeatures()[i].setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: 'normal 600 14px Calibri, sans-serif'
            })
    }));

}
```

But I've got the error

> Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: Expected feature to be
>   removed from index

How can I bypass that?

Comment: Is there are a reason that you are using per-feature styles? Wouldn't it suffice to set the style on the vector layer?

Comment: If you can, let's finish this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
var features = vector_service_port.getSource().getFeatures();
features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.getStyle().getText().setFont('your desired font');
});
```

Comment: getStyle() doesn't seem to work (I'm on ol3) I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of null" error

Comment: Then you need to show some more code, are you able to put this on a fiddle?

Comment: I'm trying, I'll let you know :)